Detect Cyclic Islands on a Matrix
On a binary matrix M, a cyclic island is a region of 1s where the region encircles itself (horizontal, vertical and cross directions are allowed)
Given a matrix M,
Allowing neighbors to be in any of the following directions:
directions = [(-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,-1)]


Return all of the cyclic islands on this matrix M.
If there are cyclic islands, turn these cyclic islands in to regular islands by turning inner area of the cycle into 1s and return the result
If there are no cyclic islands return the matrix M

Example:
M = 
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

has 3 cyclic islands located at indices.  While the islands can be defined in various ways, one example would be
a = [[0, 2], [1, 1], [1, 3], [2, 1], [2, 2], [2, 3]] 
b = [[2, 3], [3, 2], [3, 4], [4, 3]]
c = [[3, 4], [3, 5], [4, 3], [4, 6], [5, 2], [5, 7], [6, 3], [6, 6], [7, 4], [7, 5]]

And filling the inside of the islands would return
Output = 
[[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

I know that DFS will be needed to find the cycles, but I can only find neighbors for each index, unable to make the connection as to how this will help me get the cycles. Given the neighbors of each index, this should create a graph since the connection is an undirected edge, but the rest seems beyond me...
To find neighbors:
M = [
 [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
 [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]]

indices = []
for i in range(len(M)):
    for j in range(len(M[0])):
        if M[i][j] == 1:
            indices.append([i,j])

directions = [(-1,-1), (-1,0), (-1,1), (0,1), (1,1), (1,0), (1,-1), (0,-1)]


neighbors = {}
while indices:
    init = indices.pop()
    current_circle = [init]
    tracker = [init]
    
    while current_circle:
        x, y = current_circle.pop()
        neighbors[(x,y)] = []
        ctr = 0
        for (i, j) in directions:
            xi, yj = x+i, y+j 
            if [xi, yj] in indices:
                current_circle.append([xi, yj])
                tracker.append([xi, yj])
                indices.remove([xi, yj])
                neighbors[(x,y)].append([xi, yj])
            elif [xi, yj] in tracker:
                neighbors[(x,y)].append([xi, yj])
     
neighbors


But I am blank after this. Any help would be much appreciated.

This is basically detecting cycles in a graph, which is a very well known and solved problem.

@Julien I don't think so. Given the 3 "cyclic islands" in the OP's expected output, it appears that a cyclic island has to not only be a cycle of 1s, but also enclose exactly one contiguous group of 0s that neighbor each other horizontally or vertically but not diagonally. The expected output would've been drastically different if it's just about detecting cycles.

Well then also mix that with detecting connected components of the graphs of 0s. This is also a solved problem... 1 - Find connected components of 0s, 2 - for each component check border exists and is all 1s.

This problem is loosely defined anyway. What if you have a border element that you can choose to ignore or not e.g. [2,1] ? What if you have e.g. many concentric alternating 'circles' of 1s and 0s creating a 'ring' island?

@Julien The problem given the expected output is fairly clearly about finding borders of flood-filled closed shapes. I would use a flood fill algorithm to find groups of connected 0s and use a contour detection algorithm to find the border of each group.

@Julien Good point about concentric shapes, although given that the ultimate expected output is really to flood fill them all, it doesn't matter if the inner shapes count as cyclic islands or not.

@Julien Ah, I just realized that given the ultimate expected output, we don't even need the intermediate step of finding borders of 1s. Just flood-fill all 0s with 1s but abort a flood fill if a 0 is found to be at the boundary.

previous comments gave me an idea. As @blhsing said, you can try flood-filling every 0 in the matrix. Each flood-fill operation on a 0 causes a region of 0's defined using the [(-1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (0, -1)] direction (note here we don't use diagonals) to become 1's. The flood-fill operation is canceled (rolled back) if it encounters the matrix border. To avoid redundant running flood-fill algorithm on a region, you can keep track what indices has already been flood-filled before using a matrix of boolean

Could you elaborate on the flood fill algorithm? The middle step of detecting cycles is not as important, the end result should fill out the 0 regions that were encapsulated by 1s. So to better define, assume there are 1s and 0s, can you turn the encapsulated 0s into 1s

Again this is a simple graph theory problem: consider the graph of the 0 cells (with their connections if they are direct neighbours in the map). Now add an extra vertex "outside" connected to the 0 cells that are on the edge of the map. Now find the connected component of "outside", these 0s are not islands. Everything else can be replaced by a 1.
